# WooCommerce popup to switch between tax/no tax

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a shop that needs a popup on the front page, that allows users to choose whether they want to see prices with or without tax.

I have searched for weeks and I simply can't find a solution.

Does it require coding, or am I missing something?

Comment: It is fairly complicated because the woocommerce tax setting is global for the site. It will definitely require some fairly complicated coding.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well there you go. Thanks for letting me know. They should actually consider making it easier to implement - quite a useful feature.

Comment: I was actually working on something similar, which is why I posted. I can probably convert it to plugin for free public use if you want to shoot me a email

Comment: I can shoot you an email, sure. Can you write it here or can I send you a PM of sorts? I'm new to Stack Overflow.